# azure template output publish profile content

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm using an Azure Template to set up a web site. I would like it to output the contents of the publish profile so that I can automate the deploying. Is this possible?

My current template looks something like this:

```
{
    ...
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "kind": "app",
            "name": "[variables('webapp').name]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('webapp').version]",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                "serverFarmId": "[variables('webapp').serviceplan.name]",
                "name": "[variables('webapp').name]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('webapp').serviceplan.name)]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "sku": {
                "name": "B1",
                "tier": "Basic",
                "size": "B1",
                "family": "B",
                "capacity": 1
            },
            "kind": "app",
            "name": "[variables('webapp').serviceplan.name]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('webapp').serviceplan.version]",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[variables('webapp').serviceplan.name]",
                "numberOfWorkers": 1
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "manifest": {
            "type": "object",
            "value": {
                "Website": {
                    "publishUrl": "...",
                    "userPWD": "...",
                    "msdeploySite": "..."
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried experimenting with the [listkeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#listkeys) function but as I understand it you need to give the id of the resource, i.e. publish profile, that you want to get and I'm not sure how to get that.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47536086/arm-template-web-app-publish-profile

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#reference) and\or [listkeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#listkeys-and-listvalue) functions for that.

it would looks something like this:

```
"publishUrl": "[reference(variables('webapp').name)[%propertynamegoeshere%]]"
```

same goes for other things; but you need to use `listkeys` function to get keys for the webapp.

Comment: Syntax is incorrect, check documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-templates-outputs

Comment: you could just add the missing `]` instead of downvoting

Comment: not just that I'm afraid, the whole syntax is wrong, and [] for properties does not work, editing now..

Comment: it does, please investigate before posting\downvoting

Comment: i supposed it may have worked on previous apiVersions, but as far as the up to date documentation goes, your original syntax would not have worked. but hey, I guess that's why there's official documentation and you shouldn't just copy paste from SO ;)

Comment: I dont know what you are talking about, Azure documentation is a piece of crap `sigh`, just take a look at [this working example](https://paste.ee/d/zkpUm/0). works right now @PedroCosta

Comment: My point is that you can't declare an output of name "publishUrl" in the syntax presented. As a property of a previously declared output object yes, you could have. But since you've proven that you can call properties in nested [] by their names, I tip my hat off to you sir. Downvote removed ;)

Comment: the point with `[]` to access property is that you are able to use variables\parameters compared to `.`. reference(x).parameter(y) doesnt work, where reference(x)[parameter(y)] does @PedroCosta

Comment: yup, I'm aware of that now, thanks, I never had such a requirement and as I never come across it in my requirements I defaulted to the documentation, that does not mention that :) BTW, is there any other documentation I should be on the look out for?

Comment: not really. there are lots of things that are not documented. thats the main take away. for instance I randomly found at least 1 place in official Azure documentation that points to my answer on SO, instead of specifying the answer. I guess I'm flattered, but that kinda gives away that they have a lot to work on :) @PedroCosta

Comment: hehehe, we all do mate, we all do :) in a way I guess that's what makes working in this biz so interesting. thanks so much, have a great day :)

Comment: oh BTW, I'll be adding this tip to https://dev.to/pnmcosta/quick-tips-for-azure-resource-manager-templates-authoring-in-visual-studio-2017--1dbm feel free to suggest any others in the comments there

Comment: here's another tip, dont use visual studio for arm templates, kinda not worth it. [here's](http://4c74356b41.com/post5683) a bunch of ideas to help you out. @PedroCosta dont forget to upvote :)

Comment: ah yes, I use Code for editing, VS for deploying, I prefer not to keep a fixed staging storage account, and the included .ps1 works really well. Unless you now tell me there's a task to run this https://i.stack.imgur.com/eovJT.jpg on VS Code? :D

Comment: you can create any task in vscode, but I usually write wrapper ps script that do the uploads need-be @PedroCosta

Comment: Yah I guess thats one approach, but I quite like it picks up on the artifacts parameters from the templates automatically. I only started with arm a week or so ago, writing a vscode task is not in the plans so far :)