# arm template web app publish profile

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I am deploying a web app using an ARM template and need to get the publish profile as an output
Is there a way to do this?
I saw this: 
[azure template output publish profile content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459094/azure-template-output-publish-profile-content/47533329#47533329)

But couldn't get it to work
I tried both with reference and listKeys but none of the properties was the publish profile

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get the [publish Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps#WebApps_ListPublishingCredentials), you could use the ARM template [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#listkeys-and-listvalue) function to do that.

```
"outputs": {
    "publishProfile": {
      "type": "object",
      "value": "[list(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('websisteName') ,'/config/publishingcredentials'), '2016-08-01')]"
    }
```

If you want to get the **publish user** or **publish password**, you could use the following code and change the **type** from **object** to **string**.

```
list(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('websisteName') ,'/config/publishingcredentials'), '2016-08-01').properties.publishingPassword
```

**Test result:**

[image]

Comment: How would we get the FTP publishing credentials?