# Retrieve the publishing credentials (publish profile) of App Service with Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

How can I get the publish profile of an App Service with Bicep? I need to output the FTP publish URL, username and password.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an existing answer here:

- [arm template web app publish profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47546755/4167200)

```bicep
param appServiceName string

var publishingCredentialsId = resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/config', appServiceName, 'publishingCredentials')

// Full publishing credentials
output publishingCredentials object = list(publishingCredentialsId, '2022-03-01')

// publishingUserName
output publishingUserName string = list(publishingCredentialsId, '2022-03-01').properties.publishingUserName

// publishingPassword
output publishingPassword string = list(publishingCredentialsId, '2022-03-01').properties.publishingPassword
...
```

Comment: Thanks. That gets me part of the way there. I am specifically looking for the (application scope) FTP publishing credentials though.

Comment: you could use the cli command `az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles` I had a look and it doesnt seem to be possible to get that in arm

Comment: That's what I suspected already. I solved the problem with PowerShell, code is here if someone else is interested: https://github.com/SvenAelterman/AppServiceCreationAtScale/blob/afa9db4cf7f3053de3b7efeb05ffd0c27f368e9b/New-AppServiceScale.ps1#L64